# "The package conflicts with an existing package" error when updating YouTube ReVanced with APK

Tags: updates, installation, apk, youtube

To clarify, my problem isn't that I can't install an app because I have a similarly-named app; I am trying to update an app I installed via APK with another one of a later version.

I had previously downloaded YouTube Revanced from revanced.io, and a new version has been released, so I want to update it with the latest APK. However, despite acknowledging that I'm trying to update the app instead of installing ("Do you want to update this app?" dialogue), it still gives the "The package conflicts with an existing package" error.

Uninstalling and then reinstalling the app, though an option I have used, is inconvenient as I lose all my settings (there's no way to export them).

Thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately the install process of an APK file from within Android is bad when it comes to problems because the problem reason is not shown to the user. The only way I know for getting a good error message is by installing the APK file via `adb install`. But that requires a Mac or PC connected via USB, enabled developer options and ADB on the device and adb installed on the Mac/PC. If you then try to install the APK using the command `adb install <somefile.apk>` you will get an error message which describes why installation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: ReVanced Extended has added an option to export and import settings to/from a JSON file. I don't think this is in the official ReVanced app, though (probably forgot to mention that revanced.io is separate from the official one).

Edit edit: For anyone who happens to chance upon this post, just know that any website that claims to be "official" other than revanced.app is fake. Don't trust 8 months ago me. I don't trust them either.

Answer (score 1):

From [the official ReVanced Discord server](https://discord.gg/revanced), this might mean that there's a signature conflict between the previous APK and the to-be-installed APK, and the only solution is to uninstall the current app first.

From its "help" server, [posted on Jan 21, 2023, by ReVanced (Bot)](https://discord.com/channels/952946952348270622/953993848374325269/1066207575886024745),

> **27  Installation is blocked due to conflicting with an existing installation**
> This implies that you must remove the previous installation to solve the conflict.

---

In addition, [the developer & maintainer suggested](https://discord.com/channels/952946952348270622/1069708489938710609/1069708489938710609) using ReVanced Manager instead and avoiding `revanced.io`.

> **meabeab** So my revanced app started stopping and i tried to reinstall it but it says "app not installed because the package conflicts with existing package" revanced is uninstalled
> **CnC_Robert** use latest patches
> **meabeab** Where to download them?
> **CnC_Robert** manager downloads it automatically
> **meabeab** But aren't you supposed to download the revanced from the site?
> **meabeab** Without the whole manager thing
> **CnC_Robert** don't say revanced.io
> **meabeab** It is revanced.io
> **CnC_Robert** fake
> **CnC_Robert** revanced.app is the only official
> **CnC_Robert** its not from us

Comment: Yeah... I know about revanced.io being unaffiliated with ReVanced itself, though I still find it more convenient. It was worth asking though